# FileOpenService throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, runtime-error, noclassdeffounderror, jnlp, java-web-start

The Java code below is throwing `NoClassDefFoundError` :

```
    FileOpenService fos = (FileOpenService)
        ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.FileOpenService");
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `javax.jnlp.FileOpenService` on your classpath?

Comment: Seems `jnlp.jar` needs to be explicitly included in the classpath: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

The JNLP API classes can only be used in applets and applications that are launched using Java Web Start.  Even if they are explicitly added to the run-time class-path of a non JWS application, they will not be available for loading.